# Error trying to render MaterialButton from Material Components

Tags: android, material-components, material-components-android

I followed the getting started guide [here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/), I don't want to migrate to `androidx` at this time so I did:

- Made sure I have the correct repositories
- Added `com.android.support:design:28.0.0-rc01` to my dependencies, since the Getting Started tutorial states this is the only thing needed if I don't want to migrate to `androidx`.
- Made sure `compileSdkVersion` was 28
- Switched to `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`
- Downloaded Android P SDK and sources (but not any of the rest that's not on the image):
  [image]
- Made sure I am using `AppCompactAtivity`
- Rebuilt the project

And I still get the error:

> The following classes could not be found:
>   - com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton

[image]

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use com.google.android.material package instead use com.android.support.
In your case **android.support.design.button.MaterialButton**

Comment: Ohh makes sense, but now I gave up and switched to androidx

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem with Android Studio 3.2 release candidates, both using com.android.support and using com.google.android.material.

I upgraded to the 3.3 canary and that specific problem went away although I now have other (unrelated?) problems (runtime failures to inflate, etc).

I can't find any documentation stating required Android Studio versions for layout editor to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the repositories section includes Google’s Maven repository google(). For example:

   ```
   allprojects {
       repositories {
         google()

   allprojects {
       repositories {
         google()
         jcenter()
       }
     }
   ```
2. Add the library to the dependencies section:

   ```
   implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
   dependencies {




   // ...
       implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
   // ...
   }
   ```